# IICS: How to increase string precision in business services response fields

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub, iics-di

I have an API call which returns a very very long string, its size is around 885412 characters. But right now I can only capture the first 255 characters of it due to some reasons.

Like as you can see from the picture below, when I hang over my mouse on the response field 'result', it shows that its type is string and its precision is 255, I guess this is the reason.
[image]

If so, how can I capture the long string completely? Is there any way to increase the precision of this 'result' field?

Below is how I wrote my swagger file now, should I define something to increase the max length here?

```
"definitions" : { 
"sg_response": {
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

}

[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, this problem is solved, the precision can be changed in the 'Output Fields' section of the business service component, do make sure to hit enter after you type the new number, otherwise it won't be changed. Hope this helps if you have similar question

Comment: Do turn this into response with some screenshot ideally - you'll make someone happy someday. And I'd be happy to upvote!